# Obtaining clustered standard errors with speedglm package (Using speedglm with multiwayvcov + lmtest + broom)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, clustered-standard-errors

I would like to use `speedglm::speedglm()` provided it is much faster than `stats::glm()`.

Here's a MWE limited to 1000 rows of the original data:

```
data <- readr::read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pachamaltese/08224b3d72ccaf6de91cf8d67a9a1908/raw/4446be520f2a7f113ce52570db3fd5afc0db8208/yotov_ch1_application1_1000rows.csv"

formula = "trade ~ log_dist + cntg + lang + clny + exp_year + imp_year"

pair <- "pair_id" # linking variable
etfe <- "exp_year" # exporter time fixed effects column
itfe <- "imp_year" # importer time fixed effects column

fit <- stats::glm(stats::as.formula(formula), family = stats::quasipoisson(link = "log"), data = data)

vcov_cluster <- multiwayvcov::cluster.vcov(
  fit,
  cluster = data[, pair],
  df_correction = TRUE
)

coef_test <- lmtest::coeftest(
  fit,
  vcov_cluster[
    which(!grepl(paste0("^", etfe, "|^", itfe), rownames(vcov_cluster))),
    which(!grepl(paste0("^", etfe, "|^", itfe), rownames(vcov_cluster)))
  ]
)

coef_test <- broom::tidy(coef_test)
```

I would like to be able to change `fit` to:

```
fit <- speedglm::speedglm(stats::as.formula(formula), family = stats::quasipoisson(link = "log"), data = data)
```

But doing so breaks the rest of the code as `multiwayvcov` returns the error `Error in UseMethod("estfun") :  no applicable method for 'estfun' applied to an object of class "c('speedglm', 'speedlm')"`

Comment: You get the error because when you fit using ```speedglm```, you get a ```speedglm``` object which is different from a ```glm``` object. So you cannot apply the function ```coeftest```

Comment: you can either do the calculations manually or stick to glm

Comment: ... or contribute a `coeftest` method for `speedglm` ...